# How to get file from a dependency on Play Framework

Tags: java, jar, playframework, playframework-2.3

Having a managed dependency declared on the `Build.scala` file, which would be the appropriate way to get a file from the dependency? (The file isn't on `resources` folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Should work if the file is included in any of the sources. Check that you are specifying the fully qualified name with packages if necessary.

If your project or some jar contains a source file `/some/folder/file.txt` then you can access the resource using that path.

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/some/folder/file.txt");
```